# When changing one To One field in admin page the object created is not selected automatically

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to Django and I encountered a weird bug.

This is model.py:

```
class ProcessTime(TaggedModel):
    first_time = models.OneToOneField('Duration', null=True, blank=True, related_name='first_time_duration',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)  
    nth_time = models.OneToOneField('Duration', null=True, blank=True, related_name='nth_time_duration',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

And in admin.py:

```
class ProcessTimeAdmin(AbstractModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('active', '__str__', 'first_time')
    list_display_links = ('__str__',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': 'first_time', 'nth_time',)}),
        ('More', MORE_FIELDS),)
```

The problem is when I want to change processTime first_time field through the admin page, when I click on a certain processTime object a pop-up opens with this object's details. (according to the fieldsets)
first_time is displayed with drop -down list.

print screen of the pop-up:

[image]

The problem is when I want to change first_time and create a new 'Duration' the new value is not selected automatically but rather added to the drop-down list and then I need to search for it from a list that is not sorted by anything.

Also, I'll point out that it worked a few weeks ago and nothing changed code-wise.

I'd like to fix that so that when I create a new 'Duration' it will appear as selected in the drop-down and I won't need to search for it.

Can I sort this list by creation time some-how?
Or maybe change the admin UI so that I can only create new Duration and won't have the drop-down list? (It's redundant since first_time is a OneToOne field)

Thanks,
Gil

Comment: I would say, you are not saving `nth_time` correctly

Comment: I don't follow.... \n my problem is with first_time.... so why nth_time?

Comment: ok, then `first_time` is not saved correctly ;)

Comment: When I create a new first_time then the new one added to the drop -down list when I finally find and choose it from the list and press 'save' - then the new value is saved correctly. I wan't it to be selected automatically or maybe change the UI so I won't see this drop down list.

Comment: did you override any of the save or model_save methods on duration or processtime?

Comment: Yes, this is save for Duration:               
`def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if VALIDATE_SAVE:
            self.full_clean()
        super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)'.`
Save for processTime is the same. 
Do you also need the _fullclean()_ function? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the problem. Apparently I had more then 10,000 orphaned Duration objects im the DB that were not related to any processTime object. The browser has a of maximum amount of objects that can be seen in a drop list - 10,000 and therefore could not connect the new Duration to the top of the list.